# how to get string array from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Realtime database structure]

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/sample");

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: dataSnapshot "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I'm new to android app development and firebase as well. i m fetching data from **sample** node and getting DataSnapshot value like below.

```text
{size=[Small, Large, Ex-Large], type=[Type 1, Type 2], color=[Red, Green, Blue], category=[T-Shirt, Jeans, Sweater]}
```

need some expect help, any suggestion will greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to retrieve those values? Also which values do you want to get from the database?

Comment: i want to set each string array on different spinner in android.

Comment: Hey @ninjajack, if you found my answer useful, do mark it correct by clicking the V- type button next to it, this helps Stack Overflow future readers, and I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve values separately, you can use a code like this:

```java
databaseReference.child("category").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                     // category is an ArrayList you can declare above
                        category.add(dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(i)).getValue(String.class));

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { // Do something for this

                }
            });
```

Similarly you can add values of other nodes in your other ArrayLists, just by changing the value of Childs in this code.

Comment: @ninjaJack, can you try the above code and tell what gets stored in category arraylist ?

Comment: its working i did bit change category.add(dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(i)).getValue(String.class));

Comment: Great, you can use similar code for other parts of your problem. Also, consider marking the answer as correct, I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Comment: but what if i want to get all string arrays at a same time..and thanks a lot for help :D

Comment: @ninjajack ah, my bad for `String.valueOf(i)`, great you spotted that :)

Comment: If you want to retrieve all of the values from your database with one query, it would be a bit more of a work. But what you can do is use a for loop on `orderByChild(String.valueOf(i))` and then loop through all the children adding the Strings you get in the different ArrayLists and then using them. This will get you all of the values you want in one query, but I wouldn't be very sure about its efficiency for large number of nodes in Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase has no native support for arrays. If you store an array, it really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names.

// we send this

```
['hello', 'world']
```

// Firebase stores this

```
{0: 'hello', 1: 'world'}
```

[Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

// **TRY THIS**

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            youNameArray = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String data = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                youNameArray.add(data);
            }
            Log.v("asdf", "First data : " + youNameArray.get(0));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/sample");

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot sampleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: sampleSnapshot "+sampleSnapshot.getKey()+" = "+sampleSnapshot.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

The difference is that in my answer I loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` to get each individual sample snapshot. The `sampleSnapshot.getValue()` call should return a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();     
    
    DatabaseReference refence = database.getReference();
    


    refence.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                    ArrayList array= new ArrayList<>();
                    
                    
                       for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                            
                           String data = ds.getValue().toString();
                           
                            array.add(data);
                                                        
                         
                            
                           

                            
                        }

                       System.out.println(array); 
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
        
            });
```

In my case `String.class` does not work instead `.toString` method works

```
String data = ds.getValue().toString();
```